# change line display setting in windows cmd (nodejs)

Tags: node.js, windows, cmd

When I display a 2d array on CMD, I want to see sth like this:

[[image]]

However, it does not display in this way, and I think it is because of the limit of the length of each line I guess. The actual display is the following:

[image]

Is there a way to change the setting so that I can display each inner array fully horizontally?

Comment: does writing `a very long string to test if there is any mishappen during display` have the same issue?

Comment: How are you trying to display it? What command or commands are you using? We cannot really assist you with facts, unless you help us by establishing those first. Please [edit] your question, with a [mcve] of the code you are using, and a representative example of the content you're trying to output. You appear to have used the [[tag:node.js]] tag, and mentioned it in your title, so I's assume that, despite no indication of how you're using it, that you have some node.js code, and at least a command to run it.